# bash, return from redirected loop, is it safe?

Tags: bash, io-redirection, function

Notice that we return from a loop, which is redirected.

I don't know, if I should worry about the write buffer of "file".

```
function f {
    i=1
    while :
    do
        echo aaaaaaaaaaaaabbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbb
        ((i++))
        if [ $i -gt 3 ]
        then
            return    # return while redirected
        fi
    done >> file    # writing to file
}

f
```

NOTE: I am aware that this function could be easily rewritten, so that is would not return from within the redirected loop. However this is just a simplified example for the purpose of this question.

So please, do not try to improve *this* code.

I am not interested in workarounds, either.

My sole question is, if there is something I should be particularly aware of. Like the file descriptor is not closed properly. Or sometimes I can expect only half of the buffer (i.e. "aaaaaa") to be written into the file.

I would like to know, if this is a very bad idea, and why? Or maybe it would work without unforeseen race conditions or similar?
(but again, I don't want answers like "it is bad because you should use this-and-this pattern instead")

Answer (score 11, accepted):

While each command may have its own write buffer, there is no write buffer that is shared between commands even built-in in bash (or even two invocations of a same command, built-in or not).

Even ksh93 which has been known to do some I/O optimisation (for instance, it will read-ahead and share some data on *input* ([causing some bugs](https://github.com/att/ast/issues/15))), doesn't do it.

So, it will be safe in that regard. After a command finishes, like your `echo aaaaaaaaaaaaabbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbb`, and provided it doesn't fork unattended process running in background, you can be guaranteed that all I/O has been done.

A few notes though. In a function like:

```
f() {
  {
    echo x
    return
    echo y
  } > file
  echo something else
}
```

In the Bourne shell (and the Bourne shell only), that `return` would break output of the inner command group, but not return from the function as in that ancient shell, that command group would run in a subshell because of the redirection (so you'd see the `something else`).

That no longer happens in modern shells like `bash`, but you'd have the same problem in bash if you wrote:

```
f() {
  (
    echo x
    return
    echo y
  ) > file
  echo something else
}
```

or

```
f() {
  {
    echo x
    return
    echo y
  } | tr xy ab
  echo something else
}
```

Beware there are cases where some commands are not waited for. In:

```
f() {
  {
    echo >(sleep 1; echo x)
    return
  } > file
}
f; cat file
```

You may find that `x` doesn't show up because `cat` is run before `echo x`.

Some shells (though not `bash`) have similar potential issues with pipeline components other that the rightmost one.